# Comparar 2 tabelas campo a campo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho duas tabelas com campos iguais. Tabela A e B

Preciso comparar o conteúdo das duas tabelas campo a campo.
Estou usando o seguinte código para encontrar os registros que tem algum campo diferente, mas gostaria que fosse mostrado no registro apenas o(s) campo(s)  diferente(s) se for possível é claro.

Segue exemplo:

```
SELECT nova.codigo   AS codigonv
      ,nova.nome     AS nomenv
      ,nova.celular  AS celularnv
      ,atual.codigo  AS codigoatual
      ,atual.nome    AS nomeatual
      ,atual.celular AS celularatual
  FROM contatonovo AS nv
  FULL JOIN contato AS atual
    ON (nv.codigo = atual.codigo)
 WHERE atual.codigo IS NULL
    OR atual.nome IS NULL
    OR atual.celular IS NULL
```

Desde já agradeço a atenção e boa vontade.

Comment: Andrea, você está passando relação entre `nv.codigo = atual.codigo` mas eles não estão inseridos no `SELECT`. Tente inserir.

Answer (score 1):

A primeira consulta volta as linhas que estão diferentes em atual,

```
SELECT codigo, CASE WHEN q.nome = a.nome THEN NULL ELSE q.nome END nome,
               CASE WHEN q.celular = a.celular THEN NULL ELSE q.celular END celular
FROM (SELECT Nova.codigo, Nova.nome, Nova.celular
      FROM contatoNovo nova

      EXCEPT

      SELECT atual.codigo, atual.nome, atual.celular
      FROM contato atual) q
LEFT JOIN contato a ON a.codigo = q.codigo
```

e a segunda consulta, as linhas que estão diferentes em nova

```
SELECT codigo, CASE WHEN q.nome = n.nome THEN NULL ELSE q.nome END nome,
               CASE WHEN q.celular = n.celular THEN NULL ELSE q.nome END celular
FROM (SELECT atual.codigo, atual.nome, atual.celular
      FROM contato atual

      EXCEPT

      SELECT Nova.codigo, Nova.nome, Nova.celular
      FROM contatoNovo nova) q
LEFT JOIN contatoNovo n ON n.codigo = q.codigo
```

Para fazer o update/insert/delete, veja o comando MERGE: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

## MERGE (Transact-SQL)

> Realiza operações de inserção, atualização ou exclusão em uma tabela de destino com base nos resultados da junção com a tabela de origem. Por exemplo, você pode sincronizar duas tabelas inserindo, atualizando ou excluindo linhas em uma tabela com base nas diferenças encontradas na outra tabela.

Comment: Isto o meu código já esta Marcelo, mas preciso saber qual campo do registro  esta diferente, caso restorne algum. exemplo, me retornou dois registros diferentes, mas em um o nome é que esta diferente era Andreia e passou para Andrea e no segundo registro alteraldo, o nome não sofreu nenhuma alteração mas o celular mudou de 31 999 9999 para 31 9 999 9999. É possível, ou vou ter que fazer via loop na liguagen de programação usando if´s?

Comment: O código é o mesmo nas duas tabelas ou ele muda também? O campo, não o SQL.

Comment: meu sql server é o 2000, por motivo de força maior. Quando executei o código que você me passou ele me retornou a seguinte mensagem:

Comment: Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXCEPT'.
Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Line 9: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Alterado. Faltaram os ENDs.

Answer (score 0):

Você não especificou como deve ser mostrado o resultado então estou propondo duas opções:

Usando esses registros como exemplo:

```
create table contatonovo
(
       codigo  varchar(5) null
      ,nome    varchar(50) null
      ,celular varchar(10) null
)
GO
create table contato
(
       codigo  varchar(5) null
      ,nome    varchar(50) null
      ,celular varchar(10) null
)
GO

insert into contato values
 ('01','primeiro da silva', '1111-1111')
,('02','segundo contato', '2222-2222')
,('03','terceiro fulano', '3333-3333')
,('04','quarto sicrano', '4444-4444')
,('05','tudo igual', '5555-5555')

insert into contatonovo values
 ('01','primeiro da silva', null)
,('02','segundo contato da silva', '2222-2222')
,('03','terceiro fulano', '3003-3333')
,('04','quartos sicrano', null)
,('05','tudo igual', '5555-5555')
GO
```

Você pode mostrar todos os registros que tem diferenças, mostrando cada registro uma vez usando um `UNION`:

```
select nv.codigo, nv.nome as [Novo nome], at.nome as [Antigo nome], nv.celular as [Novo Celular], at.celular as [Antigo Celular]
from contatonovo nv
join contato at on at.codigo = nv.codigo
where coalesce(nv.nome,'') != coalesce(at.nome,'')
UNION
select nv.codigo, nv.nome as [Novo nome], at.nome as [Antigo nome], nv.celular as [Novo Celular], at.celular as [Antigo Celular]
from contatonovo nv
join contato at on at.codigo = nv.codigo
where coalesce(nv.celular,'') != coalesce(at.celular,'')
```

ou mostrando uma diferença por registro desta maneira salientando qual campo está diferente, novamente usando `UNION` p/ juntar tudo num dataset só:

```
select nv.codigo, nv.nome as [Novo valor], at.nome as [Antigo valor], 'Nome' as [Diferença]
from contatonovo nv
join contato at on at.codigo = nv.codigo
where coalesce(nv.nome,'') != coalesce(at.nome,'')
UNION
select nv.codigo, nv.celular, at.celular, 'Celular'
from contatonovo nv
join contato at on at.codigo = nv.codigo
where coalesce(nv.celular,'') != coalesce(at.celular,'')
```

Para o exemplo dado os resultados seriam:

```
codigo Novo nome                 Antigo nome        Novo Celular Antigo Celular
------ ------------------------  ------------------ ------------ --------------
01     primeiro da silva         primeiro da silva  NULL         1111-1111
02     segundo contato da silva  segundo contato    2222-2222    2222-2222
03     terceiro fulano           terceiro fulano    3003-3333    3333-3333
04     quartos sicrano           quarto sicrano     NULL         4444-4444
```

ou

```
codigo Novo valor                Antigo valor     Diferença
------ ------------------------- ---------------- ---------
01     NULL                      1111-1111        Celular
02     segundo contato da silva  segundo contato  Nome
03     3003-3333                 3333-3333        Celular
04     NULL                      4444-4444        Celular
04     quartos sicrano           quarto sicrano   Nome
```

**Nota:** Se você tem o **Visual Studio** ele vem com uma razoável ferramenta de comparação de bancos capaz de comparar Schema ou Dados.

Comment: Obrigada Jean, está foi "boa por demais" como se diz lá na minha terra.

Comment: Preciso  comparar duas tabelas sql com campos iguais mas que podem ter conteúdos diferentes ou uma ter mais ou menos registros que a outra.

Comment: @AndreaFerreiraGarcia ai é outra pergunta mas contanto que vc tenha uma chave única (normalmente a PK) é fácil ver quais registros estão numa ou noutra tabela. Vc realmente deveria experimentar as ferramentas de comparação de bases do visual studio

Answer (score 0):

> *Preciso comparar duas tabelas sql com campos iguais mas que podem ter conteúdos diferentes ou uma ter mais ou menos registros que a outra.
>
>   (...) gostaria que fosse mostrado apenas o(s) campo(s) diferente(s)*

Eis outra abordagem:

```
-- código #1
SELECT A.codigo, N.codigo,
       [nome atual]= case when coalesce(A.nome, '') <> coalesce(N.nome, '')
                          then A.nome else '' end,
       [nome novo]= case when coalesce(A.nome, '') <> coalesce(N.nome, '')
                         then N.nome else '' end,
       [celular atual]= case when coalesce(A.celular, '') <> coalesce(N.celular, '')
                             then A.celular else '' end,
       [celular novo]= case when coalesce(A.celular, '') <> coalesce(N.celular, '')
                            then N.celular else '' end,
       Observação= case when A.codigo is null and N.codigo is not null
                             then 'Contato incluído'
                        when A.codigo is not null and N.codigo is null
                             then 'Contato excluído' 
                        else '' end
  from CONTATONOVO as N
       full outer join CONTATO as A on A.codigo = N.codigo
  where coalesce(A.nome, '') <> coalesce(N.nome, '') 
        or coalesce(A.celular, '') <> coalesce(N.celular, '')
  order by coalesce(A.codigo, N.codigo);
```

O código acima considera que as colunas `nome` e `celular` contêm *string*.

---

O código #1 pode ser reescrito com o uso de CTE, de modo a melhorar a legibilidade:

```
-- código #2 v2
with CONTATOS as (
SELECT A.codigo as codigoA, N.codigo as codigoN,
       coalesce(A.nome, '') as nomeA, coalesce(N.nome, '') as nomeN,
       coalesce(A.celular, '') as celularA, coalesce(N.celular, '') as celularN
  from CONTATONOVO as N
       full outer join CONTATO as A on A.codigo = N.codigo
)
SELECT codigoA, codigoN,
       [nome atual]= case when nomeA <> nomeN then nomeA else '' end,
       [nome novo]= case when nomeA <> nomeN then nomeN else '' end,
       [celular atual]= case when celularA <> celularN then celularA else '' end,
       [celular novo]= case when celularA <> celularN then celularN else '' end,
       Observação= case when codigoA is null and codigoN is not null
                             then 'Contato incluído'
                        when codigoA is not null and codigoN is null
                             then 'Contato excluído' 
                        else '' end
  from CONTATOS
  where nomeA <> nomeN
        or celularA <> celularN
  order by coalesce(codigoA, codigoN);
```

Comment: José dias, funcionou perfeitamente com esta tabela com 1 campo só como chave primária. Precisei fazer o mesmo com uma tabela que tem 3 campos e todos eles compõem a chave primária, e preciso, do mesmo modo atenrior, testar campo a campo e verificar se uma tabela tem mais ou menos registros que a outra. Pode continuar me ajudando?

Comment: A princípio bastaria colocar as 3 colunas que compõem a chave primária na cláusula ON e fazer o tratamento para definir a coluna Observação. // Poste informações sobre como estão declaradas as 3 colunas que compõem a chave primária.

Comment: Estou usando o SQL Server 2000 e Delphi 4.0